# In an AC coupled Op-Amp circuit where do input bias currents flow from?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, circuit-analysis, analog, bias

If we have an AC coupled amplifier like the one below, i've read and been told it needs a DC path to ground to allow input bias currents to flow, though I just can't get my head around this, I bias is drawn from ground? physically how does this work?

[image: AC coupled amplifier]

With reference to the circuit below the bias current seems to be drawn up from ground, fi no input is provided where is the driving source? is this related to internal biasing and therefore the power rail is the source?

[image: analysis circuit for calculating effects of Ibias and Voffset]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed Ib+ in the 2nd drawing is indeed flowing out of the ground.

There is nothing strange about that **but** you need to realize that in order to draw a current "out of the ground" and through a resistor (or an opamp input), you would need a **negative voltage**.

So the opamps used in the circuits you show **need** a **negative supply rail** assuming that the opamps have a biasing current which flows **into** the opamp.

There are also opamps which have a biasing current flowing **out**
 of the inputs (yep, sounds weird!) for example the [LM324](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm324-n.pdf). This opamp is designed so that it can work **without** the negative supply voltage but still work with its input voltages close to the ground voltage.

Answer (score 1):

1. \$I_{BIAS}\$ is either passed through R1 to ground or, supplied from ground via R1. Either way depends on the type of op-amp and the power supply arrangement (dual or single).
2. The driving source is the output pin of the op-amp. It will adopt a voltage that satisfies the requirement to drive the bias current through resistor R2 whilst maintaining Vin- and Vin+ at precisely the same level.

Comment: damn that makes a lot of sense, can anyone else confirm this to be the case so I can accept my dude's answer and move on with life?

Comment: You can wait a day for other answer of course. It's no big deal (providing you do come back!)

Comment: @AndrewDavis Yup, I can confirm that to be the case.